# Code for Greater number python - showing wrong number greater error

Tags: python-3.x

while coding for a simple code of greater number, I get the output as the 1st number is greater whereas the greater number is the 2nd one

I have a small code of python where python doesn't recognize the greater number. Please help me to explain what is the case.

well if you look at the code then you will realize it's not a big deal but when you think about it in an atomic level you will know that the error is big.

```
a = 55.0000000000000009
b = 55.0

if (a > b):
  print("a is greater")
else:
  print("b is greater")
```

The actual output should be a is greater whereas it is showing the opposite.

Comment: Note what's printed if you try to print `a`. `55.0000000000000009` can't be accurately represented.

Comment: I did a dumb retraction, so I can't reclose, but this would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I did not understand. explain it properly. I am new to the programming.

Comment: Decimal numbers are stored as approximations. Not every possible number can be represented. The closest number to `55.0000000000000009` that can be stored is `55.0`, which is what `a` ends up holding. The link I posted to explain it far better than I can.

Comment: If you need complete accuracy to many decimal places, you need to use special types of numbers (often referred to something like a BigDecimal), or store it as an integer instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: In this situation its``` a== b ```because they are close values

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
a = 55.0000000000000009
b = 55.0

if (a > b):
  print("a is greater")
elif (a < b):
  print("b is greater")
else:
  print("They are Equal")
```